# Why the class constant value is getting evaluated in one statement and not in other?

Tags: php, string, class, syntax, class-constants

I'm using **PHP 7.2.6**

I've tried following program :

```
<?php

  class beers {
    const softdrink = 'rootbeer';
  }

  $rootbeer = 'A & W';

  echo "I'd like an {${beers::softdrink}}\n"; //Output : I'd like an A & W

  echo "I'd like an {beers::softdrink}\n"; //Output : I'd like an {beers::softdrink} 

?>
```

In the above statement, in first echo statement value of the class constant `softdrink` is evaluated as the string **'rootbeer'** which in turn a variable name which contains the string **'A & W'**. The value **'A & W'** gets printed.

In second echo statement I only want to show the value present in the class constant `softdrink` which is the string **'rootbeer'**.

But I'm not able to do it. Please help me in this regard.

**P.S. :** Please don't ask me to achieve the output using string concatenation. I want to achieve the output only by using the class constant within a **double quotes string**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include constant in string without concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203943/include-constant-in-string-without-concatenating)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : My question is about class constants and the question you linked as duplicate is about normal constant, so please remove the 'Duplicate' mark on my question.

Comment: There's no difference in how a class constant and a "normal" constant is treated in a string, so the duplicate is very much valid.

Comment: Did you take this example from an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333755/class-constant-in-a-string-in-php)? If so, read the accepted answer where it tells you it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik this is **not** possible. The whole "variable parsing" (extended curly syntax) in strings is done base on variables. Variables always start with a $ sign, so not starting with a $ does not seem to work. (i.e. Everything which is not (part of) a variable cannot be used.).

Simplified example (which wont work):

```
const TEST = 'A & W';
echo "I'd like an {TEST}\n";
```

Same for function calls (which also do not work directly)

```
$test = '   A & W   ';
echo "I'd like an {trim($test)}\n";
```

Only in "sub" curly braces the desired output can be used, but it has to be parsed as a variable again which makes it impossible (at this point).

Does work:

```
$AW = 'A & W';
$test = '   AW   ';
echo "I'd like an {${trim($test)}}\n";
```

Edit:

If you truly WANT to output a (class) constant inside a complex curly brace expression:

```
class beers {
    const softdrink = 'rootbeer';
}

function foobar($test) {
    $GLOBALS[$test] = $test;
    return $test;
}

echo "I'd like an {${foobar(beers::softdrink)}}\n";
```

**This is far from what I would recommend to do!!!**

Comment: Does the value of class constant evaluated and used internally only when we use the code {${trim($test)}} in double curly braces?

Comment: It does, but then you have to use it somehow as a variable again. The only workaround would be to define an extra function and introduce uglyness beyond foobar (see updated answer)

Comment: The line {${foobar(beers::softdrink)}} should have to output 'A & W' as $rootbeer = 'A & W';(According to my code)

Comment: I think you wanted the output rootbeer instead of A & W, else the question would be irrelevant. ("In second echo statement I only want to show the value present in the class constant softdrink which is the string 'rootbeer'.")

Comment: Yes, I want to but my doubt is why it's not getting evaluated again as the variable of same name also exists?

Comment: The variable is overwritten in the global scope. To solve this problem, prefix the global. Like: 

function foobar($test) {
    $GLOBALS['myfoobarprefix' . $test] = $test;
    return 'myfoobarprefix' . $test;
}

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this -

```
echo "I'd like an ". beers::softdrink ."\n";
```

Comment: I guess you missed the OP's statement in the bottom of the question: _"Please don't ask me to achieve the output using string concatenation. I want to achieve the output only by using the class constant within a double quotes string."_

Comment: Okay.. I have again answered it!

Comment: Okay.. I have again answered it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using printf -

```
printf("I'd like an %s\n", beers::softdrink);
```